# How to add Request for PHP to Yii2 Project

Tags: php, class, yii2, namespaces, include

i want to use [Requests for PHP](https://requests.ryanmccue.info/) in my yii project.

I installed the yii2 basic template, and copied the Requests Class File (and the Requests directory) to root/vendor.

I include the requests.php file with this line

```
include('../vendor/Requests.php');
```

But i always get an error that yii cant find the requests.php class.

What i need to do to implement the requests class?

Answer (score 0):

Use Composer, as proposed in [project README](https://github.com/rmccue/Requests/tree/v1.7.0#install-with-composer). Run this command in root of your project:

```
composer require rmccue/requests
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. i follow the steps and installed Requests with composer. when i try using requests now, i got the following error: "Requests_Exception
No working transports found". Do you have an idea how i can solve the problem?

Comment: No, but at least this means that you're installed package properly. You should ask about this error in another question.